# Presentation for non commutative algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let A be a non commutative algebra. Suppose that A is generated by a finite number of elements. Is it true that A has a finite presentation?

Thank you.

...

I think I should rephrase my question. Let $A$ be a non commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra generated by a finite number of elements, is it true that $A$ has a finite presentation.
More precisely, there exists a surjective map  $\psi : A \rightarrow \mathbb{C} <X_1,...,X_r>$, where $\mathbb{C} <X_1,...,X_r>$ is the free non commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra generated by $X_1,...,X_r$. Is it true that $Ker(\psi)$ is generated by a finite number of elements.

In the case where $A$ is commutative, as  Alex Youcis mentions, it is a consequence of the Hilbert's basis theorem.

Is there a similar theorem in the non-commutative case?

Thanks.

Comment: What does finite presentation mean here? Do you mean that there is a surjection $\mathbb{Z}\langle X_1,\ldots,X_n\rangle\to A$ where $\mathbb{Z}\langle X_1,\ldots,X_n\rangle$ is the ring of non-commuting polynomials with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients, and the kernel is also finitely generated? Then, the answer should be no since it's not even true in the commutative case.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, actually I meant a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra but what you say seems to be true in this case. Could you just tell me why it does not work in the commutative case? I mean, could you give examples of ideals of $\mathbb{C}[X1,...,X_{n}]$ which are not finitely generated?

Comment: No, because $\mathbb{C}$ is Noetherian :) I didn't know you were speaking of Noetherian rings!

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand you. Do you mean that the statement about the presentation of a finitly generated \mathbb{C}-algebra is true?

Comment: If $R$ is Noetherian, then so is any finitely generated algebra over it (this is Hilbert's basis theorem)--in particular $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is Noetherian. So, suppose that $A$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra. Then, $A\cong R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$. Then, $A$ is finitely presented since it's finitely generated and $I$ is finitely generated, since $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is Noetherian, and $I$ is an ideal of $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation, I didn't know the Hilbert  basis theorem. All this is very good but I am really intrested in non commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebras. Do you know a similar theorem for the non-commutative case? Or do you know a counterexample? Again thank you for helping me.